# Looking for an online gardening journal app/site

Tags: planning

I am starting a new garden. I would like to journal my progress to keep track of what I have done, add photos (ideally on the go with an app), schedule reminders (eg when planting a potato I'd like to schedule reminders for what to do with/to it in the future so I don't forget). That sort of thing. and notes on my thoughts, progress, etc. I am fairly sure nothing of the sort exists but maybe you have used other platforms for a similar purpose?

I am trialing gardenzine right now but so far I am not convinced. I hasn't found any of the plants I entered so I had to add everything by hand. And I think it will be quite restrictive in the free use and reluctant to throw money at it until I am sure it does all the things.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the community consensus is that this is off-topic. (https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/634/do-we-really-want-questions-asking-for-off-site-resources)

Comment: @Stephie (Sorry, don't know how to reach out privately/in meta.se) I  iniitally thought this should be closed per the ideals of other stackexchange sites - but when I read https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/teaching-a-man-to-fish-garden-and-shop Section 2 (3) says this kind of question is on-topi under the guideline  **Questions asking for resources are on-topic provided it is not a "big-list" or "compile all possible options" type of question.** - if this is no longer the case, maybe that needs to be changed.

Comment: You can always start a growlog on a gardening forum (such as TomatoJunction.com). It won't schedule reminders, but it covers everything else (and other people might remind you manually). Here's the Growlog forum, specifically: https://www.tomatojunction.com/viewforum.php?f=65&sid=17e071fe6bfa960bcd59df8c90868d03